# Internal Server Error with Trac: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trac'"

Tags: apache, error-handling, httpd.conf, internal-server-error, trac

I'm installing Trac on a new RHEL 8 server and am getting an Internal Server Error in the httpd error log:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trac'
```

I've tried looking in audit logs with

```
journal -xe | grep httpd
```

(and also grepped for **trac**, and **apache**) - and zero error information shown there either.

`httpd` starts normally without error.

Trac is configured to use wsgi, it's not the standalone version that has its own built in server. Apache HTTPD should be error handling.

Here is the httpd trac.conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac /data/www/virtualhosts/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
 
<Location "/trac/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Issue Tracker"
  AuthUserFile /data/www/virtualhosts/trac/conf/trac.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
 
 
<Directory /data/www/virtualhosts/trac/cgi-bin>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    # For Apache 2.2
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    # For Apache 2.4
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

and trac.wsgi

```
import os
 
def application(environ, start_request):
    if not 'trac.env_parent_dir' in environ:
        environ.setdefault('trac.env_path', '/data/www/virtualhosts/trac')
    if 'PYTHON_EGG_CACHE' in environ:
        os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE']
    elif 'trac.env_path' in environ:
        os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = \
            os.path.join(environ['trac.env_path'], '.egg-cache')
    elif 'trac.env_parent_dir' in environ:
        os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = \
            os.path.join(environ['trac.env_parent_dir'], '.egg-cache')
    from trac.web.main import dispatch_request
    return dispatch_request(environ, start_request)
```

python version

```
[user@box] # python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

I'm at a loss on why I can't get any error information to either display on screen or preferably write to a log file. This server isn't production so I can have stuff on screen for now.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd try running [TracStandalone](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#BasicAuthorization:Usingahtpasswdpasswordfile) to verify your Trac installation. Also, check permissions on `trac.wsgi` and maybe share your Apache site file content.

Comment: should trac.wsgi be executable?  Currently 644

Comment: tracd starts up without error from command line, but I cannot test since port 8080 is blocked at a network level in my org

Comment: Yes, `trac.wsgi` needs to be executable by Apache.

Comment: Set trac.wsgi to executable, restarted httpd still getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trac'`

Comment: Can you share your Apache site config file?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/uPNcY4Vi

Comment: trac.wsgi is here: https://pastebin.com/PKYNMqCM

Comment: also added to question above

Comment: Nothing is coming up in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` when you navigate to the page?

Comment: nope, although I am using RHEL so it's /var/log/httpd/ but nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the permissions on the `cgi-bin` directory or one of its parents.

The `trac-admin` `deploy` command will create a `trac.wsgi` for you, but you need to deploy outside your environment directory, otherwise, you'll get this error:

```
Error: Resources cannot be deployed to a target directory that is equal to or below the source directory '/Users/rjollos/Documents/Workspace/trac-dev/tracenvs/proj-1.4/htdocs'.

Please choose a different target directory and try again.
```

If your environment is `/data/www/virtualhosts/trac`, run:

```
$ trac-admin /data/www/virtualhosts/trac deploy /data/www/virtualhosts/www
```

Then point your virtualhosts file to `/data/www/virtualhosts/www/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi`.

Comment: Continue go get `[Mon May 03 17:59:34.043574 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 250003:tid 139841006806784] [client IP:16389] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trac'` after applying above and restarting httpd.

Comment: Is the default Python on your system path Python 3 rather than Python 2? Check `python --version`.

Comment: `python --version` Python 2.7.17

Comment: The problem is with the Python path. Also I think your trac.wsgi needs `#!/path/to/python` at the top. What is the output of `which python`? Where is Trac installed? Does `python -c import trac` succeed?

Comment: `which python` /usr/bin/python.  Trac is installed to `/data/www/virtualhosts/trac/`.

Comment: `python -c import trac` fails with:  File "<string>", line 1 
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` is at the top of the trac.wsgi file - just didn't copy it into my pastepin.  Still getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trac'` after restarting httpd

Comment: `/data/www/virtualhosts/trac/` is your Trac environment. The Trac application should be installed in Python site-packages.  I mistyped earlier, could you try: `python -c "import trac; print(trac.__file__)"`

Comment: That command yields `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/trac/__init__.pyc`

Comment: Seems like it shouldn't be necessary, but you could try adding [WSGIPythonPath](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/configuration-directives/WSGIPythonPath.html) directive: `WSGIPythonPath /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`. I'm not sure where to place it. I would try after `WSGIScriptAlias`, and if that fails, after `WSGIApplicationGroup`

Comment: I am also getting this error. I have a working trac machine  where trac was installed using apt and lives in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/. This time I used pip (for trac 1.5.x) installed to  ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ and I'm getting the "no module" error. I wonder if it's just an environment variable?

Comment: My solution was simply to install trac as root (sudo pip install trac). Then trac libraries installed to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages and now it loads perfectly in apache.